# Select2 Ajax not Calling wp_ajax_ in Wordpress (Javascript error, not a WP error)

Tags: ajax, wordpress, select, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have tried everything I can think of, but I am not able to get Select2 Ajax to call the Wordpress wp_ajax action.

Here is my functions.php (excluding the enqueueing and the localizing of the script):

```
function get_list_posts() {
  $search = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['list_search'] );
  $post_type = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['post_type'] );

  $post_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type' => $post_type,
      'post_status' => 'published',
      's' => $search
    )
  );

  // Bail if we don't have any results
  if ( empty( $post_query->results ) ) {
    wp_send_json_error( $_POST );
  }

  $results  = array();
  foreach ( $post_query->results as $post ) {
    $results[] = array(
      'id' => $post->ID,
      'text' => $post->title
    );
  }

  wp_send_json_success( $results );
  die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_list_posts', 'get_list_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_list_posts', 'get_list_posts' );
```

And my javascript:

```
  $('#list-search').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
      url: ajax_post_params.ajax_url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
        post_type = $(this).attr("data-post-type");
        return {
          action: 'list_posts',
          list_search: term,
          post_type: post_type
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, params) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(params);
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });
```

In debugging the ajax gets to the data function and the 'return', but never makes it to calling the action (or at least the PHP for that function never runs). Any suggestions to how I can figure out what is wrong with this? I believe this is a javascript error and not a Wordpress error, which is why I have it in stackoverflow, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are there any errors in your JS console? Does the request generate any errors in your network tab? Is a request ever generated?

Comment: No I can't find any errors generated from it in the console or network tab.

Answer (score 0):

As on the example https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax, you need to return the results in processResults function.

Comment: Thanks I had that at one point but changed it. I corrected it above, but the function never gets to that point, because there is something going wrong before that happens in the data function.